# tracking vault updates in corda

Tags: corda

I am using corda 3.3. And listening to Cash.State changes using,

```
val (snapshot, updates) = proxy.vaultTrack(Cash.State::class.java)
snapshot.states.forEach { logger.info("listen to inital pdates...."+it.toString()) }
updates.subscribe { update ->
    if(update.produced.size>0)
        update.produced.forEach { logger.info("listen to new produced updates ....."+it.toString()) }
    if(update.consumed.size>0)
        update.produced.forEach { logger.info("listen to new consumed updates ....."+it.toString()) }
}
```

where proxy is rpc connection. Interestingly, i am able to see the udpates of state objects other than Cash.State too. Thought proxy.vaultTrack(Cash.State::class.java) will restrict listening to Cash.State only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that was fixed here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/3276. The fix will be included in Corda 4.